# Crystal Report: Print bill - do not print blank section

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I using Crystal report (CR) to print bill, my printer is OKI Microline 5790, I set up my report is: size Letter, orientation Portrait.
The content of bill (from Report header to the signature of cashier) just 1/2 of size Letter. But the printer print a page Letter with the content of bill and a space after that. That lost my time, I must roll back the paper then cut it.
I cann't set up report is size A5, orientation Landscape because the printer will print orientation Portrait (Rotate 90 degree).
I want the printer just print the content of bill, then stop to i can cut it, have not to roll back the paper.
Please help me. Thanks all very muck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Questions that are not about programing are not on-topic for this site.  You might be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or another forum.

Comment: Check the temporary txt file that is created before the report is printed. It is possible that file itself has blank space at the bottom and needs trimming. you can find the txt file by typing %temp% on your Windows "Run" function. Sort folder by descending and run report.